# How to make the sounds from this Donkey Kong 2 composition (Super Nintendo)?

Tags: synthesizer, video-games, replication

The soundtrack from the Donkey Kong series on the SNES (Super Nintendo) is definitely one of the best for me. That's why I want to know how to reproduce some sounds.

The brass/pad (?) starts at 0:36 and I really wanna know how to make the same exact sound. I assume that it was sampled because most music for SNES was made with a music tracker if I'm not mistaken. But what synth produces that kind of brass? What would the patch be and how many oscillators are used and in what waveforms?

I'm also very curious to know how to reproduce the humming sounds at 1:24.

Could it be that the orchestra hits you hear is from Roland's VSC3? What effects are being used? Or is it layered? The dry sound from VSC3 sounds thin and thus doesn't sound the same as in the DK example.

Comment: I'm not near a synthesizer to try and recreate them so can't give a proper answer, but for the pad, try a subtractive synth with a bunch of saw waves (use unison), and put a lowpass filter on them with a bit of modulation. For the humming, look into formant processing. You can make an EQ that mimics an "ooo" vowel, and put that over some sort of source sound.

Answer (score 2):

it sounds like some sort of pad, are you sure that's brass? definitely a wet sound. try to find a pad in your DAW that sounds somewhat similar. Add a flanger effect and toy around with the decay. Shorten the release up too. I think you'll be able to recreate it that way.

The humming sound is a guy going "o0o0o0o-o0o0-o0o" but with a vocoder effect on it. I think there's reverb on it too.

Comment: you are right, pads sound more like it. I kinda meant the "horn-ish" sound you can hear. It sounds like that horn sound has like 0 attack and blends with the pad's release. Right now I am trying to recreate and the flanger effect helps. I found out that layering also helps, but I'm still trying and searching. Thanks for your answer.